# Regex expression: replace first and last if special character

Tags: regex

I need help with a problem. I am using regex to find a specific string that ends and begins with a special character. The string can contain words, special characters and spaces. Only the special characters at the end and the beginning should be selected.

Examples:

`.Hello i´m Jonas"`

Result:

`Hello i´m Jonas`

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try a regex replacement on the following pattern:

```
Find:    ^\W(.*)\W$
Replace: $1
```

This would only match an input whose first and last characters are not word characters.  It captures what comes in between, and the replaces with that captured term.

### Demo

If your requirement is actually to optionally remove a special character at the beginning *or* end, then use an alternation:

```
Find:    ^\W|\W$
Replace: (empty)
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you it works. Can I perhaps make it so that if he finds something at the front he only deletes at the front and if he finds something at the back he only deletes at the back? Example: "Hello Result: Hello

Comment: To be more precise: I want to delete either the front, the back or both.